# Import a JS function inside of YAML file

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, amazon-sns

I'm trying to pass custom variable inside of yaml file which will be computed in a separate file.

Is there a way I can do that?

**github-workflow.yaml**

```
variable:
  message: computeTheString()

name: My Trigger
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [labeled]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: [ default ]

    steps:
      - name: Step name here
        run: echo ${{ variable. message }}
```

**computeTheString.js**

```
export function computeTheString() {
    return JSON.stringify(slightlyLongerString)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the pipe symbol (|) which indicates a multi-line entry. here's an [example](https://awstut.com/en/2022/02/02/3-parterns-to-create-lambda-with-cloudformation-s3-inline-container/#toc10) of CloudFormation with inline function:

```
variable:
  message: |
    export function computeTheString() {
      return JSON.stringify(slightlyLongerString)
    }
```